# Errors in PL/SQL codes for "+"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

This is my code from the Manual [Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdauF.jpg)

Getting this error when I typed the code in "Run SQL Command Line" [ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZDCB.jpg)

But when I copy pasted the same code line by line from my manual it got executed [Executed Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxwV4.jpg)

Even though both the codes are same, I'm getting the "+" error at the end. Tried spacing between the variables and ":=" but still getting the error when I write it. Why it's happening so?

THANKS IN ADVANCE..!

Comment: Please don't put links with images. User formatted text for your code and error messages.

Comment: `sum` is a keyword, thus the error. In your `executed code`, the variable name is **sum1** not **sum**. That's when you copy-paste it executes successfully. Change the name of the variable.

Comment: @NickKrasnov Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3):

In your error image you declare a variable called sum.  This is an [Oracle keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions197.htm#SQLRF06115) and is the cause of the error.

If you change the name to sum1 as is shown in your sample it will run.